# How do I set push-state in durandaljs 2.0 the works on refresh?

Tags: durandal, pushstate

I'm using durandaljs 2.0.  I've installed the durandal starter-kit as suggested and explained [here](http://durandaljs.com/pages/get-started/).  In the shell I'm returning `router.activate({ pushState: true } );` as explained in the relevant [documentation](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router/) (see the bottom of the page).
Happily, the URL is indeed in a 'push state' format, e.g. `http://localhost:61285/flickr` - the problem is that when I refresh the page I get a 404 error telling me "the resource cannot be found".  If I set push-state to false (`{pushState: false}` above) I get a hashed URL, e.g. `http://localhost:61285/#flickr` - and now a refresh does work.  So, how do I set up a push state mode in durandaljs 2.0 that will work with refresh?

Thanks,

Elior

Comment: Looks like you haven't configured a server side handler for http://localhost:61285/flickr?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe to late...but

just change the routes config.
simple as this :

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{*url}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Answer (score 3):

When you refresh the page, the browser will make a request to the server with that URL `http://localhost:61285/flickr`.

What's probably happening is that if you are using ASP.NET MVC, the server is trying to locate a Controller called `flickr` and it throws an exception because obviously there isn't any resource with that name.

In order to get rid of this exception  **you should configure the server to serve the same HTML of the APP but for unknown URL's. This can be achieved using IIS URL Rewrite in ASP.NET.**

So after setting up properly the server, by requesting an unknown URL it would return the initial view for the app plus whatever you pass in the query string parameters so the router can do its job at client side.

[In this blog post](http://tarkus.me/post/32121691785/angularjs-with-asp-net-mvc-4) you will find more information about how to configure ASP.NET to handle this scenarios. In the article the author uses AngularJS, however it will be the same for Durandal.

Answer (score -1):

RainerAtSpirit and margabit, you're both right, thank you.  Here is how I implemented the server side:

First I should note that all the interaction with the server is done via `WebApi` controllers.
so, for example, if the URL is: 
`http://localhost:61285/home/category2/subCategory22` (for a localhost), the server tries to look for a controller called 'home' and an action in it called 'category2'.  Since there's no such action, I get a 404 error. 
What I wanted is that the server WILL call the 'home' controller, but send the rest of the URL as parameters to the client.  My solution was to add a **hash** after the controller's name, so that the URL will look like this: `http://localhost:61285/home/#/category2/subCategory22`.  If this would happen then the client will take care of the hashed part with no 404 error.  
For this to happen:

I added the following to 'web.config':

> <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error">
>      <error statusCode="404" redirect="Error" />
>   </customErrors>

Then I create a controller named 'ErrorController' with the following class in it:

> ```
> public class ErrorController : ApiController
> {
> [HttpGet, HttpPost, HttpPut, HttpDelete, HttpHead, HttpOptions, AcceptVerbs("PATCH"), AllowAnonymous]
>     public HttpResponseMessage Handle404()
>     {
>         string [] parts = Request.RequestUri.OriginalString.Split(new[] { '?' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
>         string parameters = parts[ 1 ].Replace("aspxerrorpath=","");
>         var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
>         response.Headers.Location = new Uri(parts[0].Replace("Error","") + string.Format("#{0}", parameters));
>         return response;
>     }
> }
> ```

what happens is that when the server get a URL with no relevant action as I mentioned above, it redirects it to this controller in the following format: `http://localhost:61285/Error?aspxerrorpath=home/category2/subCategory22` 
as you can see, I manipulate this to add the hash and remove the unnecessary info: `http://localhost:61285/home/#/category2/subCategory22` and the redirect the server to the 'home' controller.

You might wonder why I do all of this - the reason is that Durandal, a wonderful platform, enables me to use push state, but in order for that to happen I have to work-around the server getting a non-hashed URL and pass it to the client despite the fact there's no relevant controller/action; Durandal get's a hashed URL but removes the hash automatically and the user eventually sees a hash-less URL while Durandal provides all the necessary push state functionality.

Elior

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. You might look into something like http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite to deal with it at the IIS instead of the WepAPI level.